# Determine if Google User has Classroom or Not

Tags: javascript, api, google-classroom

I have integrated Google Classroom into my app. But occasionally regular Google users, who do not have Google Classroom, will sign in with Google.

How can I tell if a user has access to Google Classroom?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to get or tell if the user has access to Google Classroom. If you check the Classroom API, the only user that you can get are the one that is inside your Classroom by the use of [Method: userProfiles.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles/get). For more information, check this [Classroom Help](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom#topic=6020277) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function getClasses(){
  try {
  var courses = Classroom.Courses.list().courses;
  return courses
  } catch (e) {
   return e
  }
}
```

If they are not a Google Apps user then e will give

> @NotGoogleAppsUser The user is not a Google Apps user.

If they have access to classroom but don't have any classes, then var courses will be undefined.